# nautilus extesions using mono?

Tags: linux, mono, nautilus

Is it possible to write nautilus extensions using mono? 
I seem to find only c and python references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [the same question](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-list@lists.ximian.com/msg32047.html) on the [mono list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/).
Seems there is no such binding.